# cross domain asmx web services is not calling from jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, web-services

I wants to call asmx web services from jquery ajax. But it  display error message "Uncaught Error. undefined"

"http://www.webservicex.com/country.asmx/GetCountries" url is different domain

My code is

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("hello");
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://www.webservicex.com/country.asmx/GetCountries",
                    //data: '{"CountryName":"india"}',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    contentType: "applicatiosn/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonpCallback: "onJSONPLoad",
                    cache: "false",
                    success: function (response) {
                        //alert(response.d);
                        alert("Services have Call");
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: Refer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Functionality is supposed to be broken in jQuery 1.5.

Since jQuery 1.5.1 you should use xhrFields param.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true
});
```

Comment: @osama_1200 you'r welcom